# Can't send sms on real device

Tags: java, blackberry, sms

I'm trying to send a message from a vector of numbers, everything works fine in the simulators but when i try it on a real device (9630) nothing happens (no exceptions thrown either). I've tried with and without port numbers and am running out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. Here is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<_cntctsNmbrs.size(); i++) {
_conn = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://"+_cntctsNmbrs.elementAt(i)+":0");
final TextMessage msgOut = (TextMessage)_conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
msgOut.setPayloadText(frmtdMsg);
_conn.send(msgOut);
_conn.close();
```

}

Comment: Is your app signed? I'm not sure but I'd think SMS apps would need to be signed.  And is the version on the real device signed?  The sim doesn't care about signing.

Comment: try to send every SMS in different threads and manage these threads using thread pool.

Comment: it wasnt even working with only one recipient, sorry i forgot to mention that, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it took was to send using a DatagramConnection, working fine now, thanks.

```
DatagramConnection dgConn; 
dgConn = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://" + _cntctsNmbrs.elementAt(i));
byte[] data = "MessageBody".getBytes();
Datagram dg = dgConn.newDatagram(dgConn.getMaximumLength());
dg.setData(data, 0, data.length);
dgConn.send(dg);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, if you're still curious it's CDMA

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageConnection message_connection = null;

     try {
     message_connection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://");
     TextMessage text_message = (TextMessage) message_connection
     .newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
     text_message.setAddress("sms://" + SMS_PHONE_NUMBER);
     text_message.setPayloadText(smsContent);
     message_connection.send(text_message);
     } catch (IOException e) {
     }
```

The above code working fine in GSM devices.